# Use unit from the main folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a simple problem i have some units in the main folder and my project is located in a sub folder and i want to use the units from the main folder. I used this :

```
uses
ACMIN in '..\ACMIN.pas'
```

I get the error : File not found ACMIN.dcu.

Comment: Is that extract from your .dpr file? If so then it should work.

Comment: Nope is from a .pas ? I must declare this in the dpr and then declare it in the .pas ? Please post an explanation i will be grateful

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Solved it thanks to you ;) You could post a detailed explanation so i can approve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you post is from a .pas file rather than a .dpr file. So far as I am aware that should be a syntax error so I'm a little confused.

As for how to do it right, I would move

```
ACMIN in '..\ACMIN.pas'
```

into the .dpr file's uses clause. The path is relative to the directory containing the .dpr file.

Then you can write

```
uses
  ACMIN;
```

in your .pas files.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path of the main file to the Project library

`Tools->Environment Options->Library->Library paths`

and you can use 
     `uses
      ACMIN`

Comment: Yes but if i deploy the project on another machine it will raise an error.

Comment: Bad idea! If ever, put the path into the unit search path of the project. Don't use an absolute path for that, use the relative one as done in the question.

Comment: Library paths are only meant for people who need to use them for certain reasons, such as custom component writing, but never for files in a project. That's what the project file is for.